# Navigation menu not showing pages under subsite in navigation menu SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have been trying to have my navigation menu show a dropdown (hierarchical) list. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/05/15/SharePoint-Tip--How-to-Activate-the-Drop-Down-Menu.aspx). But, when i try to create a new page, it does not show under my subsite.

For example, I have SiteA-> SubSiteA1 (showing)-> Page.aspx (not shown in the navigation menu).

I have been looking on google and this forum but I cant see to find a solution! I tried re-activating the Server Publishing feature but it does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

If you activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature, you need go to Site Settings > Navigation, then select Show subsites in Global Navigation section.